# Open Hyperlink VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**Objective:** open 4 excel workbooks from specific directory paths, which are listed in the "macros" tab, range "C2:C5"

**Issue:** I've recently started using VBA.  Code gets through testing until "ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink hL.Value"

**Question:** Where did I go wrong?

Thanks for any comments

**Code:**

```
Sub Update1()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim hL As Range

    Set Sh = Worksheets("macros")
    With Sh
        Set Rng = .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    For Each hL In Rng
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink hL.Value
    Next hL

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `hL.Value`? It should be a hyperlink like `"http://www.google.com"`

Comment: If it's a folder path Excel might show a security warning "location may be unsafe". Do you get any error or message?

Comment: Try `For Each hL In Rng.Cells...`

Comment: What is the output of your code?  An error: "address of this site is not valid" or something else?  How do things look when you step through with the debugger?  There is no obvious reason your code would not work.

Comment: @314UnreadEmails, the given syntax is OK if `Rng` is a valid `Range` object (i.e. not `Nothing`).  You do not need to iterate `Cells` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink hL.Value
```

try

```
Workbooks.Open(hL.Value)
```

(Assuming you have the full paths combined with file name in your list.)

Comment: Can you explain the why you think `Open` will work where `FollowHyperlink` does not?  A quick test on my end shows that `Open` will not follow a folder path whereas `FollowHyperlink` will (with a warning).  Also, if it does work, it needs to be `Workbooks.Open hL.Value` since you are not `Setting` a variable with that call.

Comment: I've never really dabbled with FollowHyperlink, but assumed it was geared toward URLs? Workbooks.Open is the standard way I've always used to open an excel workbook given a path... Yeah brackets are optional, agreed. I simply think it looks tidier...

Comment: @Agent_K, can you provide a sample of the text that is in those cells?  I am very surprised that a valid path to a workbook gets handled differently by the two methods.